# Android Studio Gradle Fabric with proxy settings "Unable to connect to the network"

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, crashlytics

I have an Android project that uses the Crashlytics with Fabric plugin on the Android Studio , set up the proxy for the files :

studio64.exe.vmoptions :

```
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-Dhttps.proxyUser=xxxxx
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=xxxxxxxx
```

gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyUser=xxxxxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080

systemProp.https.proxyPassword=xxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyUser=xxxxxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

For some reason I can not log into the plug giving the message "Unable to connect to the network"

Anyone have any ideas or possible solution to this problem ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this, any workaround ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: And Fortunately I got :)

Comment: Did anyone get solution for this??

Answer (score 10):

Navigate to

```
Android Studio directory > bin
```

Add below lines to `studio.exe.vmoptions` and `studio64.exe.vmoptions`

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=PROXY_ADDRESS
-Dhttps.proxyPort=PROXY_PORT
-Dhttps.proxyUser=USER_NAME_HERE
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=PASSWORD_HERE
```

It is working perfectly fine with Android studio 2 Beta 5 for me .

**UPDATED:**

If you have any special characters in your username or password like "Domain/Userid" make sure you replace you your special characters with ASCII Encoding Reference here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: @BMU It was working for me, Sorry but I am no longer on a proxy environment so can't test if for you. I have only one thing which I have updated in my answer, please check.