# Fabric plugin in Android Studio Unable to connect to the network

Tags: android

I have installed Fabric plugin in Android Studio. But I'm unable to work with it because when I'm trying to login "Unable to connect to the network" error appears. Web version only gives guidance on how to install the plugin. Vicious circle.

Android studio 2.3.3, Fabric for Android Studio plugin version 4.1.1.

Any ideas on the issue?

**Update**
Here is the screenshot of the error message:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it will help much, but can you post a screen shot of the error?

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879164/android-studio-gradle-fabric-with-proxy-settings-unable-to-connect-to-the-netwo?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you. But I don't understand what values I should set and where do I get them. Can you help me with this? Are those values (PROXY_ADDRESS etc.) system constants?

Comment: Does your network connection use a proxy for web browsing, etc.? If not then the linked answer is irrelevant. It was all I found on google, though.

Comment: As far as I can see my connection doesn't use any proxy